# Order By Twice Within A Column

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, sorting

Suppose we have a NAME table like this:

```
PERSON_ID   PART_TYPE   VALUE
```

and `PERSON_ID` is a foreign key reference to `PERSON`.

Inside `PART_TYPE` would be values like `FAMILY`, `GIVEN`, `PREFIX`, `SUFFIX`, etc. Values would be the actual value, naturally.

How would you write a SQL query (let alone Hibernate) to have this ordered by the `PART_TYPE`, then the `VALUE` for the `FAMILY` `PART_TYPE`, then the `VALUE` for the `GIVEN` `PART_TYPE`?

Consider the scenario where you have these three people:

```
Given3 Family10
Given5 Family10
Given7 Family10
```

With this SQL:

```
SELECT this_.person_id, name1_.part_type, name1_.value
FROM person this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN name name1_
ON this_.person_id       =name1_.person_id
ORDER BY (
  CASE
    WHEN name1_.PART_TYPE = 'FAMILY'
    THEN 0
    WHEN name1_.PART_TYPE = 'GIVEN'
    THEN 1
  END),
  name1_.VALUE,
```

I get:

```
  ID2  FAM Family10
  ID1  FAM Family10
  ID3  FAM Family10
  ID4  GIV Given3
  ID5  GIV Given5
  ID6  GIV Given7
```

I want:

```
ID1  FAM Family10
      ID2  FAM Family10
      ID3  FAM Family10
      ID4  GIV Given3
      ID5  GIV Given5
      ID6  GIV Given7
```

Thus, the order of the those Family10 rows in the current state are indeterminate -- it could be any combination of ID1, ID2, and ID3. I want them ordered according to the Given values. I'm really not sure how to do this, even with multiple select statements.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to get those person ids and I can do some filtering on my end to get distinct person ids and do some paging logic on it, then actually load the Person (thereby cutting down on a lot of SQL calls). I can't change the database schema at this point in time.

Comment: Someone feel free to edit the title line if they can think of a better way to describe it. I was struggling with that.

Comment: Could you give an example of desired output and what ORDER BY you have now?  Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I'm a little confused

Comment: @dweiss I added in an example of what I want. Is that any more clear? I also changed the ids to make that less confusing. I do have the ORDER BY clause in the SQL snippet I posted, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit different than what you're asking for, but perhaps it's helpful - it gives the family and given name for each person.

```
SELECT this_.person_id, family.value as family, given.value as given
FROM person this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN name family
    ON this_.person_id = family.person_id
    and family.PART_TYPE = 'FAMILY'
LEFT OUTER JOIN name given_
    ON this_.person_id = given.person_id
    and given.PART_TYPE = 'GIVEN'
ORDER BY family.value, given.value
```

Comment: That looks correct. Wow, you're awesome! I will accept this. Any chance you know how to do this in Hibernate?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Hibernate at all. I'm sure somebody else can help you out though.